# problem in setting width of some elements in css

Tags: css

````
my html:-
```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>i-Educate - New way to learn</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar background">
            <div class="navbar-left">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="" id="logo">
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-right">
    
                <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search here">
                <button class="btn-search">Search</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section class="container background">
            <div class="para">
                <h1>This is the modern way of learning</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore magni, ut optio dolorum dicta minus repudiandae fuga itaque veniam corrupti nulla, cum fugit eveniet repellendus. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit
                    facere, vel consequuntur deserunt iusto inventore voluptas eaque atque tempora. Corporis voluptatibus, sed aliquid iure distinctio, ipsa perferendis necessitatibus quam, vero excepturi rem ratione recusandae. Quo nemo consequatur blanditiis
                    neque eos commodi quam debitis doloribus nostrum, numquam suscipit ipsa vitae veritatis?</p>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="btn">Subscribe</button>
                    <button class="btn">Watch here</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img">
                <img src="logo.jpg" alt="laptop">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <h1 class="heading">About us</h1>
            <div class="main-box">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus dignissimos quibusdam quos laborum aliquid repellendus minima iure est temporibus voluptatibus voluptas possimus fuga vel, molestiae at hic quo necessitatibus voluptatum excepturi
                        animi rem doloribus omnis tempore. Optio sapiente quo, architecto dolore hic ea molestiae at adipisci consectetur libero quasi possimus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus velit perspiciatis pariatur earum
                        debitis blanditiis nemo, harum repell </p>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?books , student" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-box">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus dignissimos quibusdam quos laborum aliquid repellendus minima iure est temporibus voluptatibus voluptas possimus fuga vel, molestiae at hic quo necessitatibus voluptatum excepturi
                        animi rem doloribus omnis tempore. Optio sapiente quo, architecto dolore hic ea molestiae at adipisci consectetur libero quasi possimus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus velit perspiciatis pariatur earum
                        debitis blanditiis nemo, harum repell </p>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/700x900/?classroom , education" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-box">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus dignissimos quibusdam quos laborum aliquid repellendus minima iure est temporibus voluptatibus voluptas possimus fuga vel, molestiae at hic quo necessitatibus voluptatum excepturi
                        animi rem doloribus omnis tempore. Optio sapiente quo, architecto dolore hic ea molestiae at adipisci consectetur libero quasi possimus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus velit perspiciatis pariatur earum
                        debitis blanditiis nemo, harum repell </p>
                </div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?coding" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="contact">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <div class="contact-box">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your email">
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Enter Your address">
                <textarea name="query" id="query" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your query"></textarea>
                <button class="contact-btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer class="footer">
            copyright preserved
        </footer>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

my style.css(styling+mediaQuery):-
````

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    #logo {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar .navbar-left {
        display: flex;
        /* background-color: red; */
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    .navbar .navbar-left .nav-list {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .nav-list li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 5px 5px;
    }
    
    .nav-list li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .nav-list li a:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .background {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) url('../bg.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-blend-mode: darken;
    }
    
    .navbar .navbar-right {
        width: 50%;
        /* display: flex; */
        /* background-color: purple; */
        text-align: right;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .navbar .navbar-right input {
        width: 20%;
        border: 2px solid rgb(26, 8, 26);
        padding: 2px 2px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .btn-search {
        padding: 2px 2px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .container {
        display: flex;
        height: 700px;
        /* border: 2px solid red; */
    }
    
    .container .para {
        /* background-color: red; */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 65%;
        padding: 5px 70px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .para h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
    }
    
    .para p {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-left: 160px;
    }
    
    .container .img {
        display: flex;
        /* background-color: purple; */
        width: 35%;
        /* justify-content: center; */
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .container .img img {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 150px;
    }
    
    .buttons {
        /* border: 2px solid green; */
        width: 65%;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .buttons .btn {
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 0px 3px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: none;
    }
    
    .buttons .btn:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .content {
        /* border: 2px solid green; */
        height: 83vh;
        background-color: #f2d8b6;
    }
    
    .content .heading {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
        /* margin-top: 5px; */
    }
    
    .content .main-box {
        border: 2px solid green;
        height: 150px;
        display: flex;
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 21px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    .content .middle-box {
        border: 2px solid green;
        border-radius: 10px;
        height: 150px;
        display: flex;
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 21px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
    
    .middle-box img {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
    .content .text {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .content .photo img {
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        /* border: 2px solid black; */
    }
    
    .contact {
        background-color: rgb(255, 241, 241);
    }
    
    .contact h1 {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    
    .contact .contact-box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .contact .contact-box input,
    textarea {
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 8px 0px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .contact-box .contact-btn {
        width: 100px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 8px;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .contact-box .contact-btn:hover {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    
    .footer {
        background-color: black;
        height: 35px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:1220px) {
        .navbar {
            border: 2px solid blue;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 350px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: 'center';
            width: 100%;
        }
        .navbar-left {
            border: 2px solid red;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .navbar-right {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .navbar-right input {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .nav-list {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .container .para {
            padding: 5px 0px;
        }
    }
```

Sir i am getting problem in setting width of the elements like navbarr-right and navbar-left , i want to center the navbar elements when the media query is applied and also want to change its width so that it should be a good looking but it is not happening.
please suggest me where i am doing wrong and in a beginner friendly way that where i have to change and what to change alongwith the clear reason because i am a begineer.

Answer (score 0):

im not so familar with web but why you don't just use #navbarleft or #navbar-right
I meanwhy you don't directly access it with the name you gave on the class name , i hope this makes a difference , try and tell me